# Dynamically selecting template specialization

Tags: c++, templates, c++03

I have a template class `Filter`, which takes an instance of another template class `Model` as its parameter. I now want to have a `vector` of different models (i.e. `Model`s with different template parameter), and be able to run `Filter` over each of them. For this I derive the `Model` from a non-template `class AbstractModel`, which allows me to put these different models into a single `vector`. All good, but then there's a problem: calling a template class' method requires to statically know template parameter. But I don't have them statically known.

Here's the code

```
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>

class AbstractFilterData {};
class AbstractModel {};
template<int N>
class Args {};

template<int N>
class FilterData : public AbstractFilterData
{ int a; };

template<int N>
struct Model : public AbstractModel
{
    static const int n=N;
    virtual void compute(Args<N>& args) const = 0;
};

struct ModelA : public Model<3>
{
    virtual void compute(Args<3>& args) const {}
};

struct ModelB : public Model<5>
{
    virtual void compute(Args<5>& args) const {}
};

template<int N, int P>
struct Filter
{
    static void predict(FilterData<N>& data, const Model<N>& model)
    {
        Args<N> args;
        model.compute(args);
    }
};

int main()
{
    // For statically-defined model this works OK
    FilterData<ModelA::n> data;
    ModelA modA;
    Filter<ModelA::n,2>::predict(data, modA);

    // Let's make a bunch of different models and put them into a vector
    std::vector<AbstractModel*> models;
    models.push_back(new ModelA);
    models.push_back(new ModelB);

    // Associated data for these models
    std::vector<AbstractFilterData*> fdata;
    fdata.push_back(new FilterData<ModelA::n>);
    fdata.push_back(new FilterData<ModelB::n>);

    for(size_t i=0; i<models.size(); ++i)
    {
        // Now I'd like to run Filter::predict() on
        // each of the models in the vector... but how?
        Filter<models[i]->n,2>::predict(*fdata[i], *models[i]);
        // This breaks on models[i]->n being not a constant-expression, of course
    }
}
```

I can think of making a loop over possible values `k` of model's template parameter, trying to do `dynamic_cast(models[i],Model<k>*)`, calling `Filter<k,2>::predict()` then, but this looks quite ugly. Also, as I don't know upper bound on `k`, I would have to guess, because making `INT_MAX` instantiations of `Filter` would make the code unusable.

Another way could be putting a static const pointer to `Filter<N,2>::predict()` method in `Model<N>` declaration, but this is also ugly, because then class `Model` will appear to be tied to class `Filter`, which breaks independence of these classes (e.g. adding another filter will not just work).

Is there a better way of traversing such set of different models and calling the `Filter<?,2>::predict()` on them? Ideally, I'd like the compiler to do all the dispatch work for me, so that no template instantiations occured for parameters which are never really used.

Comment: do `n` have to be static?

Comment: @user1810087 `n` is static, but `models` isn't.

Comment: You may dispatch with a `switch`.

Comment: @Jarod42 yeah, not much different than a loop over all possible `k`. Doesn't look very automatic too. I'd like to have some way to tell the compiler to do this job of dispatching for me.

Comment: @Ruslan Could you please specify what is the actual problem you are facing? What is the end result? What is this hierarchy supposed to be used for?

Comment: @Jefffrey I'm trying to implement a [Kalman filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter), which would be general enough to work with arbitrary dynamic system model. What makes me implement models as template classes is that the state vectors which they work with have varying dimension, which is the template parameter. Several different models will be used to describe a single system so that the results will later be processed by [IMM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radar_tracker#Interacting_multiple_model_.28IMM.29) to obtain final estimate of target position.

Answer (score 0):

This is pseudocode, many things omitted.

```
class AbstractModel {
    virtual int Order() = 0;
};
class AbstractModel {
    virtual int Order() = 0;
};

template<int N>
class FilterData : public AbstractFilterData {
    virtual int Order() { return N; };
}
template<int N>
class Model : public AbstractModel {
    virtual int Order() { return N; };
}

multimap<int, AbstractFilterData*> dataMap; // dataMap[i] contains a pointer to 
                                            // FilterData<i> 
multimap<int, AbstractModel*> modelMap;     // modelMap[i] contains a pointer to 
                                            // Model<i>
```

Now you can do lots of things. You can pass `AbstractFilterData*` down to your `compute` and it will downcast the argument as necessary. You can pass the entire `dataMap` to `compute` and it will fetch and downcast the needed data. You can hide `dataMap` in a class that only has template members

```
template <int N>
void Put(FilterData<N>);
template <int N>
FilterData<N> Get();  // or perhaps FilterDataIterator<N>, if you really
                      // need a multimap
```

and does all the the casting itself, and pass around that class. Or you may reverse the entire thing and do the same with `modelMap` instead.